# How to debug @graphql-codegen/cli

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen

Having difficult understanding where these errors are coming from. Adding `--verbose` and `--debug` to the command do nothing. I just want to know specifically what is causing the schema to fail to load. No matter what url I provide, it always fails. This wasn't happening before.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this I'm not seeing?

```
(node:11248) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[STARTED] Parse Configuration
[SUCCESS] Parse Configuration
[STARTED] Generate outputs
[STARTED] Generate src/generated/graphql.tsx
[STARTED] Load GraphQL schemas
[FAILED] Failed to load schema
[SUCCESS] Generate outputs
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be fixed if you upgrade your @graphql-codegen/cli.

Check documentation:
https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/config-reference/codegen-config#debug-mode

Check issue:
https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/925#issuecomment-468618967

```
$ graphql-codegen --debug  --config codegen.yml
✔ Parse Configuration
⚠ Generate outputs
  ❯ Generate to src/types/api/index.ts
    ✔ Load GraphQL schemas
    ✔ Load GraphQL documents
    ✖ GraphQL Document Validation failed with 23 errors;
      Error 0: Cannot query field "..." on type "..."
```